# Data not being received when sent by CURL

Tags: php, curl

I am sending data via post command of curl. data is sent using array but when i receive, it just contains 1 and 0. Could you tell how to receive data that is being posted by curl. 
Heres my code for curl.php file: $data array is being posted

```
        <?php
    $data=array(
    'product_name' =>'Television',
    'price' => 1000,
    'quantity' => 10,
    'seller' =>'XYZ Traders'
 );
 $url = 'http://localhost/API2/products';
 $ch = curl_init($url);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
 $response_json = curl_exec($ch);
 echo $response_json;
 curl_close($ch);

 ?>
```

i am trying to get the posted data from curl in my products.php file using $_POST. But i receive one's and zero's

```
    echo"Got here ";
    $_product_name=$_POST["product_name"];
    $_price=$_POST["price"];
    $_quantity=$_POST["quantity"];
    $_seller=$_POST["seller"];
    echo"data:= "+$_product_name+$_price+$_quantity+$_seller;
```

So is it the right way to get data out of array being sent from curl or do i need to loop through array.

Comment: you have to use `$response_json` instead of `$_POST`

Comment: it doesn't work. and how do i use $response_json. i am sending array of data.

Comment: $response_json is the data or header value passed from my products.phpfile to curl inorder to show response.

Comment: You have to format the post body before sending.

`curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($data));`

Comment: thanks i am trying to receive the data on products.php sent from curl. How do i get the data because it gives me 1's and zero's . $_product_name=$_POST["product_name"];
  $_price=$_POST["price"];
  $_quantity=$_POST["quantity"];  I am trying to get using $_POST. so how to unpack data from the http build query